# Accessing secure resource with spring resource

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I am trying to integrate spring security into my application and for some reason (unknown to me) I keep on getting a 403 error on every request. I am convinced it has something to do with spring security. Below is a snippet of my code for further details.

This is my first attempt of integrating spring security to my application so I could be missing something.

I have this in my WebSecurity class

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private UserService userService;

@Autowired
private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

@Autowired
private JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider;

@Bean
@Override
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
}

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .httpBasic().disable()
            .csrf().disable()
            .cors().disable()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers( HttpMethod.POST, "/auth/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .apply(new JwtConfigurer(jwtTokenProvider));
}

@Override
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
}
```

And in my controller I have this

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/auth")
public class LoginController {
@Autowired
private UserService userService;

@RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json", consumes = "application/json")
@ResponseBody
public Response<UserDto> register(@RequestBody Request<UserDto> request){
    MessengerUser user = userService.saveUser(request.getData());
    return new Response<>(new ModelMapper().map(user, UserDto.class));
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/sign-in", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json", consumes = "application/json")
@ResponseBody
public Response<LoginDto> signin(@RequestBody Request<UserDto> request) {
    LoginDto loginDto = userService.authenticateUser(request.getData());
    return new Response<>(loginDto);
   }
}
```

With my Request 
    {
        "data":{
            "username": "username",
            "password": "password"
        }
    }

My suspicion is that it has something to do with my configuration but I'm not sure what else to try.

Comment: How are you calling your endpoint? Can you show the request url?

Comment: As far as I understand JWT, you should be sending authorization token with each request (which you get after a successful user authorization/login). Are you doing that?

Comment: I figured what out what my problem was. After spending quite sometime on it, I realized my HTTP request was not set properly. 
Stupid mistake on my part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, it was my mistake. I had the wrong request type, Silly mistake on my part.

Everything about was right but the request type was `GET` instead of `POST`